# What uniform is this?

Tags: military, identification, uniform

At a family reunion in Alberta my brother showed me a photograph of a young man in a dress military uniform. The photograph was on paper using a process common at the turn of the century. I can't find any uniform that looks like this. Any help in determining what his uniform is would be greatly appreciated.
[image: young man in dress military uniform]

Comment: Do you know what year the photo was taken in? Approximately?

Comment: No idea what year it was taken, sorry

Comment: If I had to guess, it looks about 1890s.

Comment: Based on the photographic technique, 1905-1915 for the date; the uniform may be from the forest service, rather than military: here is the US equivalent, 1906: http://westernheritagestore.com/Merchant2/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Store_Code=WHC&Product_Code=FS450&Category_Code=USFS

Comment: Hi Peter, wow, thanks. That makes a lot of sense. To this day, conservation officers, as they are now referred to, wear a uniform and enforce laws. I hadn't even thought about it. It certainly explains a lot about what's missing from his uniform, such as insignia, rank, division and so on, not to mention a weapon. Cheers

Comment: Is the family immigrants of a European country?

Comment: The subject looks really young. Could it possibly be a uniform from a military school?

Comment: Yes, our family on my father's side were Russian speakers from southern Ukraine, near Odessa.

Comment: It's certainly possible he could be wearing a military school uniform. If it was taken in Alberta in the early part of this century I would be willing to bet there were no military schools, but it's worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

This is a 1910 pattern Swedish army uniform.  See http://yourswedishheritage.blogspot.se/2014/05/tuesdays-tip-uniforms-of-swedish-army.html for a comparison